# ffmpeg command to copy video config from ffprobe

Tags: ffmpeg

What's the command to convert an MP4 to the output format similar to a video with this `ffprobe`:

```
ffprobe version N-82151-g1e660fe Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 35.100 / 55. 35.100
  libavcodec     57. 65.100 / 57. 65.100
  libavformat    57. 57.100 / 57. 57.100
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 66.100 /  6. 66.100
  libswscale      4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Input #0, avi, from '.\sample.mp4.hd.mojo':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.57.100
  Duration: 00:37:28.85, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10461 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 960x540 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 9745 kb/s, 20 fps, 20 tbr, 20 tbn, 20 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 22050 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 705 kb/s
```

I've tried

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -c:v mjpeg -c:a pcm_s16le -an output.mp4
```

The output however does not play with the [custom player](https://support.ncomputing.com/portal/en/kb/articles/vcast-what-is-the-difference-between-web-media-and-mojo).

**Update:**

I found a file which seemed to contain some config:

[image]

```
[high]
label=High quality
labelHelp=Converts to high quality
outSuffix=hd
codecParam=-vcodec mjpeg -vf scale=min'(960,iw)':-1 -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 22050 -ac 2 -r 20 -q:v 2
[medium]
label=Medium quality
labelHelp=Converts to medium quality
outSuffix=mid
codecParam=-vcodec mjpeg -vf scale=min'(960,iw)':-1 -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 22050 -ac 2 -r 20 -q:v 5
[low]
label=Low quality
labelHelp=Converts to low quality
outSuffix=low
codecParam=-vcodec mjpeg -vf scale=min'(960,iw)':-1 -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 22050 -ac 2 -r 20 -q:v 8
[main]
label=Convert to NComputing MOJO
labelHelp=Transcodes original file format to the NComputing MOJO format
outSuffix=
codecParam=
```

Comment: If I use the Windows tool from context menu that NComputing provides with the same input it works and play, but when I use ffmpeg it won't play, so something must be wrong with my ffmpeg config. I need to be able to use ffmpeg command line so I can automate the process and also do this no just on windows but also with Linux servers.

Comment: The mojo thing is making AVI: `ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -c:v mjpeg -c:a pcm_s16le -f avi output.mojo`. May or may not work as I do not know if the mojo ffmpeg has been altered or if it's just using one of the publicly available static builds. If it's just regular ffmpeg, without more info we can only guess what command mojo is using.

Comment: I tested the output of this command `ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -c:v mjpeg -c:a pcm_s16le -f avi output.mojo` it crashes the player

Comment: Your ffmpeg is over 4 years old. [Get a new one](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/). Maybe it needs 22050 Hz. Add `-ar 22000`. Not much to go with here given the lack of info provided (no log of your command, is mojo using a custom ffmpeg?, can you see the actual ffmpeg command mojo uses in the software somewhere?), so I'm just throwing out guesses.

Comment: I found some kind of file that seemed to contain some configuration which I posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made it to work.

So to make a MOJO video file for NComputing devices here's the ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -vcodec mjpeg -vf scale=min'(960,iw)':-1 -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 22050 -ac 2 -r 20 -q:v 8 -f avi output.mojo
```

For low quality video. For other video quality just refer to the mojo.col file.